# Page numbering is off-center

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page-numbering, document-classes

I received a template that supposedly satisfies the [criteria](https://graddiv.ucsc.edu/current-students/pdfs/dissertation-thesis-guidelines.pdf) for a master's thesis submission at my university but for some reason, all the page numbers are noticeably left-of-center. The ".cls" file is quite lengthy, but I've copied portions that look relevant below. An example page is also included below.

I am looking for either help debugging the misplacement of the numbers or even just a hack to shift them back to the center. I thought it might be related to the `oneside` option, but even if I use `twoside` the page numbers are off-center to the left.

Here are potentially relevant excerpts of the .cls file

```
%    ****************************************
%    *               OPTIONS                *
%    ****************************************
%
% Option values are now declared first thing.  Defaults are set to
% 11 point, onesided, final (ie not draft) mode (BBF 10/31/94)
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\newcommand\@draftmark{}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\renewcommand\@draftmark{1}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\renewcommand\@draftmark{0}}
\ExecuteOptions{11pt,oneside,final}
```

...

```
%  Two-side or one-side printing.
%
% \@twosidefalse               %  Default is one-sided printing.
\def\ds@twoside{\@twosidetrue  %  Defines twoside option.
           \@mparswitchtrue}   %    Marginpars go on outside of page.
```

...

```
\if@twoside         % If two-sided printing.
\def\ps@headings{\let\@mkboth\markboth
\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}%       No feet.
\def\@evenhead{\rmfamily \hfil\thepage\hfil \slshape \leftmark}%  Left heading.
\def\@oddhead{{\slshape \rightmark}\hfil \rmfamily\thepage \hfil}% Right heading.
\def\chaptermark##1{\markboth {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
     \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}{}}%
\def\sectionmark##1{\markright {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
  \thesection. \ \fi ##1}}}}
\else               % If one-sided printing.
\def\ps@headings{\let\@mkboth\markboth
\def\@oddfoot{{\slshape \rightmark}\hfil \rmfamily\thepage \hfil}%\def\@evenfoot{}%     No feet.
\def\@oddhead{} \def\@evenhead{}% Heading.
\def\chaptermark##1{\markright {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}}}
\fi
```

...

```
\def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hspace{0.75in}\hfil}        % foot (right)
\def\@evenfoot{\hfil\thepage\hspace{0.75in}\hfil}}      % foot (left)
```

...

```
\if@twoside\else\raggedbottom\fi % Ragged bottom unless twoside
                                 % option.
\if@twocolumn
 \@@input twocolum.sty\relax
\else
 \onecolumn                 % Single-column.
\fi
```

And here is an example page:

[image: example page]

Comment: Can you please add the link to the .cls file for someone here to reproduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yeah,

```
\def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hspace{0.75in}\hfil}        % foot (right)
\def\@evenfoot{\hfil\thepage\hspace{0.75in}\hfil}}      % foot (left)
```

it is clearly declared to be half of 0.75 inch (0.375in) left of center.

I also expected the problem to be the difference between \oddsidemargin and \evensidemargin with the [twoside] option.

Comment: That's it, thanks! I thought it would be an easy fix for anybody who knew what they were doing, but I didn't know what those commands *did* so I didn't know that the \hspace would cause the page number to be off-center.

Comment: The `\hfil` at each end is horizontal filling, which causes `\thepage\hspace{0.75in}` to be centered on the line.

Comment: There's also an earlier instance of `\@oddfoot` that wouldn't be centered either, but the one you show here overrides that.  I'd say this `.cls` file needs a good housecleaning.  (Like many thesis `.cls` files.)

Comment: I'd definitely agree with that. It's dated "31 October 1994." I was barely born.